# Can't find Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, keras

I'm trying to use an env in Anaconda that uses these frameworks: `conda install tensorflow numpy scipy opencv pillow matplotlib h5py keras`.

When I activate the env I get the following error but Visual Studio (v14) is installed.

> Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - exiting

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

I am trying to run the code in Analytics Vidhya "Understanding and Building an Object Detection Model from Scratch in Python" - https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/06/understanding-building-object-detection-model-python/